# Cannot find local variable Android Studio debug Android Studio 2.4 Preview 2

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I cannot access variables while debugging after upgraded AS. I searched on Google that the problem comes from build.gradle config:

```
debug {
      testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

But it's not in mine. Does anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I downgraded my AS to 2.3, and gradle 2.3.0 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

Now AS can view local variable perfectly. In AS 2.4 Preview, it required update to gradle 2.4.0-alpha1. I guess problem comes from gradle. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha1'